# Just sent the whitehat address .33 some odd ETH by accident

Tags: ether

I'm positive this is a dumb question. 
tx 0x88d4c8eb40d05d7f99f57ce54fa170a59919b6920e5cc4ec9e125f8518c747a2
to address 0x1dba1131000664b884a1ba238464159892252d3a

I had the multisig whitehat address up, and i was making a bittrex withdrawl. Copied the wrong address.

This isn't coming back to me is it.

Comment: You should ask them in reddit.com/r/ethereum.